# dynamic multiple filters in xsl

Tags: xslt

```
<list>
<field ows_ID="1081" Program="106;#Virginia" ProgramCategory="United States"/>
<field ows_ID="1082" Program="110;#NewYork" ProgramCategory="United States" />
<field ows_ID="1083" Program="106;#Texas;#112;#Virginia;#118;#Mass" ProgramCategory="United States" />
<field ows_ID="1084" Program="111;#Florida;#180;#Texas" ProgramCategory="United States" />
<field ows_ID="1085" Program="" ProgramCategory="Australia" />
<field ows_ID="1086" Program="122;#Sydney;#Melbourne" ProgramCategory="Australia" />
<field ows_ID="1087" Program="121;#Melbourne" ProgramCategory="Australia" />
<field ows_ID="1088" Program="118;#Mass" ProgramCategory="United States" />
<field ows_ID="1088" Program="123;#Brisbane" ProgramCategory="Australia" />


</list>
```

I have some xml out of which I need to find count where ProgramCategory is equal to some Country and Program should not equal to some states which I am getting dynamically from some other xml. From the other xml I am getting Program associated with each ProgramCategory and then I need to filter above xml with the condition

```
foreach(list/field[@ProgramCategory=$Country][not(contain(@Program,$State1][not(contain(@Program,$State2][not(contain(@Program,$State3][not(contain(@Program,$State4])
```

The problem is that I can get n no. of states which I am getting through for loop of other xml.

So Say, if I got from another xml that states associated with United States are Virginia, Texas and Florida then the count for United States is 2 and If I say states associate with Australia are Melbourne, Sydney and Brisbane then count is 1. I am using xsl 1.0.

Comment: The fact that you have mulitple state names in a single attribute is really messing it up isn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, +1.

**I think there isn't a single XPath 1.0 expression** that evaluates to the wanted count.

**Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pFilteredStates">
  <state>Virginia</state>
  <state>Texas</state>
  <state>Florida</state>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:param name="pCountry" select="'United States'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vFiltered" select=
  "document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pFilteredStates']/*
  "/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vCount">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select="string-length($vCount)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:if test=
  "@ProgramCategory = $pCountry
  and
   not($vFiltered[contains(current()/@Program,
                           .
                           )
                 ]
      )
  ">
   <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<list>
    <field ows_ID="1081" Program="106;#Virginia" ProgramCategory="United States"/>
    <field ows_ID="1082" Program="110;#NewYork" ProgramCategory="United States" />
    <field ows_ID="1083" Program="106;#Texas;#112;#Virginia;#118;#Mass" ProgramCategory="United States" />
    <field ows_ID="1084" Program="111;#Florida;#180;#Texas" ProgramCategory="United States" />
    <field ows_ID="1085" Program="" ProgramCategory="Australia" />
    <field ows_ID="1086" Program="122;#Sydney;#Melbourne" ProgramCategory="Australia" />
    <field ows_ID="1087" Program="121;#Melbourne" ProgramCategory="Australia" />
    <field ows_ID="1088" Program="118;#Mass" ProgramCategory="United States" />
    <field ows_ID="1088" Program="123;#Brisbane" ProgramCategory="Australia" />
</list>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
2
```

**II. XPath 2.0 solution**:

The following single XPath 2.0 expression:

```
count(
   for $f in /*/*,
       $w in $f
             [@ProgramCategory eq $pCountry
            and
              not($pFilteredStates/*
                           [contains($f/@Program, .)]
                  )
             ]
     return $w
      )
```

**when evaluated on the same XML document (above), produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
2
```

Comment: I tried the xsl 1.0 solution and its giving me count of 5, any idea?

Comment: @Jack: You either changed (maybe without noticing) the XML document and/or the code or you have a very buggy, incompliant XSLT processor. I always test my solutions before publishing them. In this case 9 XSLT processors (both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0) produce exactly the same, correct result: `2`. MSXML3, MSXML4, .NET XslCompiledTransform, .NET XslTransform, Saxon 6.5.4, Saxon 9.1.5, AltovaXML (XML-SPY), Altova-XML for XSLT 2.0, XQSharp. You may check and validate this result with any of these XSLT processors.

Comment: I tried it here http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/HGv9mi and its showing 5, can you tell me where I am going wrong..?

Comment: @Jack: Don't use such sites -- of course they are buggy. I only get this error: "*Object doesn't support property or method 'transformNode'*" -- and this means they can't even initiate the transformation. C'mon man, use MSXML 3.0 (comes with IE) and the msxsl.exe command utility. If I can have and use more than 9 XSLT processors, what is it that is stopping you from having at least so many?  We are professionals -- no online "cakes"...

Comment: @Jack: I really tried to use this "cake" with FF -- strongly recommend *not* to use it. I couldn't run a single transformation -- worse than alpha status -- complete F A I L.

Comment: @Jack: Not to mention that they refer you to http://w3fools.com -- complete tragedy.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. I am not able to use document() in my xslt as the xml-xsl converter we are using is custom and I cannot change how its transforming things..I am trying to find some other way to do it but I will post it as a new question. I am marking it as answer, logically it looks fine..

Comment: @Jack: The use of `document()` is just for convenience. In a real application the parameter will be set externally and just used as `pFilteredStates`. In case one needs to have this parameter with hardcoded default value (as in my answer) then if `document()` isn't allowed, one needs to use the xxx:node-set() function on `pFilteredStates` in order to extract a "normal tree" from its RTF (Result Tree Fragment). There are many code examples doing this in many answers -- just look at them and you'll be able to do the same.

Comment: Dimitre - could you elaborate further on what you feel is so negative about XsltCake.com? It uses the browser's native XSLT processor, so if you use a good, modern browser you have very good, recent XSLT processor to run the XSL on.

Aside from that, I tried the link in question in FF 3.6 (old, I know) and it doesn't return the error.