# adding multiple filters

Tags: xslt

As I have mentioned in this post:
[dynamic multiple filters in xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363393/dynamic-multiple-filters-in-xsl)
Basically, I want to apply multiple filters to my xml using "for loop" and these filters are dynamic which are coming from some other xml

sth like this:

```
foreach(list/field[@ProgramCategory=$Country][not(contain(@Program,$State1][not(contain(@Program,$State2][not(contain(@Program,$State3][not(contain(@Program,$Staten])
```

The problem is that I can get n no. of states which I am getting through for loop of other xml.

I cannot use document() function as suggested by Dimitre so I was thinking of achieving it by:

```
 <xsl:variable name="allprograms">
    <xsl:for-each select="/list2/field2">

            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">[not(contains(@Program,'</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@ProgramID"></xsl:value-of><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">'))]</xsl:text>
                                                            </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

gives me something like this:

```
[not(contains(@Program,'Virginia'))][not(contains(@Program,'Texas'))][not(contains(@Program,'Florida'))]
```

I want to use this above value as a filter in the for loop below and I am not sure how to achieve that

```
<xsl:for-each="list/field[not(contains(@Program,'Virginia'))][not(contains(@Program,'Texas'))][not(contains(@Program,'Florida'))]">
```

Before this I also have a for loop to filter United States

```
xsl:for-each="list/field $allprograms">
   <xsl:value-of select="@ows_ID" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want my answer to be 1082, 1088..

I can add the xml here too if there is any confusion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jack,

From the previous solution you just need to add to this:

```
 <xsl:param name="pFilteredStates"> 
  <state>Virginia</state> 
  <state>Texas</state> 
  <state>Florida</state> 
 </xsl:param>
```

the following (changing the current variable definition that relies on the `document()` function):

```
<xsl:variable name="vFiltered" select= 
  "ext:node-set($pFilteredStates)/* 
  "/>
```

Where the `"ext:"` prefix needs to be bound to this namespace (this is the EXSLT namespace -- if your XSLT processor doesn't implement `exslt:node-set()` then you need to find what `xxx:node-set()` extension it implements, or tell us what is your XSLT processor and people will provide this information):

```
"http://exslt.org/common"
```

So, your `<xsl:stylesheet>`  may look like the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
```

I still recommend that the `$pFilteredStates` parameter should be passed by the initiator of the transformation -- in which case you can delete the definition of `$vFiltered` and replace every reference to it with $pFilteredStates` and the transformation should work OK.